# How to invoke textbox automatically from backgroundworker?

Tags: c#, .net

In the backgroundworker I am receiving data string through TCP/IP.I want to invoke it directly to Textbox in WFA without using any button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.AppendText(textFromTcp)));
```